# Desert Sand Blowing Into My Attic

Tags: attic, vent

We live in the high desert of Southern California and our home is positioned facing South and the prevailing winds blow from the West.  Our gable vent faces West and over time the sand has blown into the attic.

I assume I'll just shop vac it up, but how do I prevent this from continuing to happen while keeping the much needed ventilation??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sand from the Sahara desert - lots - blows into the Bahamas and is the number one source for land additions in the region.   You are dealing with something in your own back yard, not a full ocean away.   That being said... Good luck with your attic!

Comment: Can you provide a photo, or sketch, to show the construction of the "gable vent". Not everybody understand that term, who might be able to offer help.

Comment: Furnace  filter?

Comment: What kind of roof? Can you switch to ridge vent?

Comment: As what @mikes said probably want some type of air filter(need to clean often) or a sediment trap.  A housing with an inlet and baffle before air goes though an outlet.  Collect sand in a bag or box.

Comment: Is converting to an unvented attic an option?

Comment: I think the likely approach here would be to baffle the vent so that the incoming air is slowed to the point that sand drops out, while still outside the house. Basically an open bottom box over the vent...or offset boards if bottom up is a problem (vent is exhausting - but seems like it's mostly intake in prevailing winds.) You'll probably have to experiment to get dimensions that work.

Comment: It depends on the weight of the "sand".  If the air is still do the particles settle out?  or is this sand so light weight that when disturbed it stays suspended in the air for a while?

Comment: Trees will naturally reduce particulate matter PM2.5.  They will also slow wind speeds.  Do you have enough room to plant trees upwind of your intake?  Do you have an overhang on the gable end ?

Answer (score 0):

Several options available.  A good roofer can offer some suggestions also...  here are a few:

1. You can find a vent with extra long louvers (louvers are the blades that are tilted - some window blinds you can twist the louvers open and closed).  The wide louver blades tilting down may not allow much sand except in strong winds to blow up and into the attic space.  Just as an example... https://www.archlouvers.com/Louver_E4WH.htm
2. Sometimes a small awning or hood over the louver/vent can block the wind & rain and may disturb the air so sand won't blow directly in to the attic.  But strong winds can bend or tear off an awning.
3. You can replace that vent in the gable end with a roof vent.  You have to consider another penetration through the roof.  Those roof vents usually have a hood to keep rain (and possibly wind driven sand) out while still providing ventilation.  Oftentimes the vent fan is mounted inside the attic space and has a thermostat to turn it on when the temp gets high (and some with humidistat if the humidity gets high).
   Good luck

Comment: Do you have any relationship to the company you're linking?